# Determine which cage length on Shimano Ultegra 6800

Tags: road-bike, parts, derailleur-rear

How can I determine which cage length is on my road bike? I have a Shimano Ultegra 6800 groupset, with 11-28 casette and 52-36 chainrings.
I found this resource, however, I measure 60 mm between the jockey wheels...
https://www.mantel.com/blog/en/derailleur-capacity-maximum-techcenter/
I also checked the Shimano website, but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

60mm on RD-6800 is a SS (short) cage. Source: I measured my RD-9000 SS. If anyone has a longer than 60mm cage on RD-5800/6800/9000, then it's a GS (medium) cage.

Comment: For the record my RD-5600 SS has a 50mm cage. I'd expect later versions to be a bit longer.

Comment: Totally agree! I contacted the producer today, on this particular bike they mounted SS cage. So Ultegra 6800 SS cage is 60 mm from axle to axle of the jockey wheels.

Answer (score 2):

Road rear derailleurs tend to have two available lengths, while MTBs have three. The page you linked to seems to be MTB focused.

See this [Shimano page](https://bike.shimano.com/content/productsite/en-EU/product/component/ultegra-6800.html#cg3SHICRearDerailleur) that shows both the SS and GS side by side, it should be easy to tell which of the two you have.